# How to use wp_query in different column in single loop

Tags: wp-query

This is my html structure. i want to display main page in left column which is column 6 and right and side 3 - 3 column which is same category and link with left page. i made page link relation with afc plugins so how can i display main page with link pages in single loop.

    
        
            
                
            
        
        
            
                
                    
                        
                            
                        
                    
                    
                        volunteering

We have placed hundreds of international volunteers from 17 to 76 years old from all over the world.
                        [![

summer program - 2 weeks
                            
                        
                    
                    
                        
                            
                                
                                    
                                
                            
                            
                                summer program - 3 weeks
                            
                        
                    
                    
                        
                            
                                
                                    
                                
                            
                            
                                summer program - 3 weeks
                            
                        
                    
                    
                        
                            
                                
                                    
                                
                            
                            
                                summer program - 2 weeks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7TaE.jpg this is layout.

Comment: So you want to display the first post from the loop on the left side in 6-wide column and 4 other posts in two 3-wide columns on the right, is that what you have trouble with?

Comment: Yes, 4 other posts in two 3-wide columns on the right they are in same category. but left 6-wide column is main page of 4 others pages. and html code is not showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the first post from the loop using a different HTML than the rest of posts in the loop just use a if/else statement.

```
$post_count = 0;

if ( have_posts() ) {

    /* Start the Loop */
    while ( have_posts() ) { the_post();

        if ($post_count == 0) {

            // Display 6-wide column
            // This will be executed just once for first post.

            $post_count ++;
        } else {

            // Display 3-wide posts
        }
    }
} else {
    // No posts
}
```

Is that the problem you encountered or did you mean something else?

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much. it works for me and for knowledge is it possible to use multiple loop in inside main query.